# Problem loading bootstrap-v5 Javascript with Django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently learning Django and bootstrap, and I wanted to test some dropdown features.
I looked for a while in my html code seeking for errors but apparently, the problem comes from the javascript and popper libraries of bootstrap that won't load properly.

When i'm making a dropdown menu, the dropdown button is displayed, but nothing happens when I click on it. Same for all the features of bootstrap requiring JS such as alerts, toasts.. But strangely, carrousels, for which the docs indicates also they require Javascript, work properly.

It doesn't matter how I try to load the JS files, it never works.
I tried to load the JS and Popper separately, by including these two lines just before the closing  tag :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I also tried the bundle :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

It never worked so I downloaded the bundle and tried to load it this way :

```
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
```

This doesn't work either. When I place a test.js in the same folder with some junk inside like document.write("test"), I can see than the file is loaded properly.

Also, the chrome console doesn't show any error. I can see that these files are loaded:

[Files loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlZix.png)

I'm using the last version of bootstrap : v5.0.1
Django 3.2.3
Python 3.8.7

The code for my navbar where the dropdown menu doesn't unroll :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Django-Tests</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
                            {{ user.username }} 
                         </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change password</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>           
    </nav>
```

But I don't think the problem comes from there, because I have the same problem when copy-pasting code from the Bootstrap docs.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually the same issue is in ReactJs the Jquery link provided from the bootstrap page for v 5.0 is not working properly, my suggestion is use jquery link of Bootstrap v.4 and css link of bootstrap v.5.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up downgrading entirely to bootstrap v4. Because I had some rendering issues with v5 CSS, especially with breadcrumbs.